# Linux history old commands

Tags: linux, ubuntu

When I enter `history | more` in Ubuntu terminal I see a list of 1000 - 2000 old commands.  How do I view even older history i.e.,  before 2000?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Increase history size by setting HISTFILESIZE. Add this line to your `$HOME/.bashrc`:

```
export HISTSIZE=9999
export HISTFILESIZE=999999
```

This will save the 9999 last commands in history.

But there's no way to see older history which already has been deleted.